# What would be the effect of gas giant was turned into a sun on a planet with no axial tilt

Tags: science-based, planets, earth-like, climate-change

Scenario: A star system with multiple planets, in particular a habitable planet which has no axial tilt [such as this](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/13318/what-if-an-earth-like-planet-had-no-axial-tilt-climate-and-technology?newreg=c37f4868c20c438c8a3d94728946b666), and the next planet out being a gas giant.

The gas giant is ignited using a method which does not change its mass such as [Thermonuclear ignition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stellification).

the orbit of the gas giant is close enough to the orbit of the habitable planet/big enough that, at the closest the two planets can get to each other, the ignited gas giant will increase the average global temperature by 7 degrees Celsius, similar to the difference of Summer and Winter.

The two planets have different years, so that the habitable planet will cool down and heat back up depending on its proximity to the new sun, creating something like seasons (which it did not initially have due to no axial tilt).

Question:

1- is this possible?

2- what effect would the intial ignition have on the habitable planet, I expect the main effects would be to weather and the life already evolved, but I would appreciate hearing about other effects as well if you can think of them.

3- What are the longterm effects on the habitable planet, in particular what would happen as the gas giant moved away from, and back towards the habitable planets.

EDIT: reworded to, I hope, be clearer.

Comment: This sounds like the Ashen *plan* to save humanity from world hunger in StarGate SG1.

Comment: Consider that weather anywhere can create temperature variations much larger than several degrees - any two days could be seven degrees Celsius apart on average and the day-night range could be much larger.  This "mini sun" would have minimal effects.

Comment: How do you plan to turn gas giants into stars?mass requirements are drastically different.

Comment: @StephenG Im thinking of a global average, similar to summer vs. winter, in my hometown the temperature difference in average high is about 6 degrees Celsius.

Comment: @Molot  I am not yet certain, hoping not to resort to "cos technology happened to figure it out magically", but I don't want to change the mass of the gas giant/mini-star either. Thats a question for another time, for the purposes of this question, assume the mass remains unchanged.

Comment: @Jared without knowing method, it is next to impossible to tell effects. If you plan to just inject mass from somewhere, it'll change orbits. If you plan to insert magical mass to energy converter, it won't, at least not that drastically. And so on

Comment: @molot OK, a quick google gives me a good contender for method [ThermoNuclear Ignition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stellification). Basically a nuclear device detonated at a depth in the gas giant where there are high concentrations of hydrogen and helium isotopes could support a fusion chain reaction.

Comment: *Scientists have proposed[citation needed]*... But well, at least it does not require changing masses.

Comment: It all depends on the power output of the alighted gas giant. For example, in our very own Solar System, Jupiter and Saturn actually output more power than they receive from the Sun, about 60% more in the case of Jupiter and 100% more in the case of Saturn; while in absolute terms the positive power output of Jupiter is enormous, *relative to the Sun* it's negligible and thus its influence of Earth is also negligible.

Comment: @Jared For artificial star-like objects you want to look at the fictional technology of **Cavitronics** invented by David Brin and the output of Hawking Radiation at a given mass.

Comment: [Obligatory XKCD](https://what-if.xkcd.com/imgs/a/150/binary.png) I'm guessing you're talking about the other kind?

Comment: @bendl, yes other kind.

Comment: @AlexP if it helps I want the alighted gas giant close enough/powerful enough to raise the average temperature of the planet by several degrees, equivalent to winter vs summer on earth, but planet wide.
The idea being when the new sun is on the other side of the star system from the planet, the planet would be almost the same as before the gas giant was lit, but if they are on the same side it would give the planet an artificial "summer", but I would imagine that there would be some huge repercussions of such a setup when it first happens, and when it settles into a routine.

Comment: Even after editing... still *Too Broad*.  Ask **one** question.

Comment: Also, for the new star to raise the planet's temperature by 7°C, it would have to be close enough that the huge gravitational and magnetic field effects from the gas giant would have played havoc on the rocky planet from the beginning.